# Templates and Partial Views - Use one OR the Other?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

So I want to verify something.  And that is to me you wouldn't need to use Partials at all if going the template route as your template is essentially providing the markup as a partial would but obviously you're doing it different via templates.

So you wouldn't use both.  I assume If I'm going to go with something like Knockout, I'd probably most likely never use partials in my MVC app, correct?

Answer (score 1):

> I assume If I'm going to go with something
>   like Knockout, I'd probably most likely never use partials in my MVC
>   app, correct?

Yes, correct. Knockout is a client side templating engine that you could use and now your controller actions will return JSON instead of partial HTML.

But I wouldn't say that if you use a templating engine you will never use partial HTML. There are many things which would be hard to achieve with a client side templating engine. For example generating forms containing antiforgery tokens, input fields with client side validation attributes, ... -> they are just more easily generated on the server.

Comment: yea that's what I'm getting at.  I don't mind not using partials.  I just wanted to verify if I go the template route that's usually the case, that you end up not using partials...as the template services similar purposes.